# My player disappears when moving back

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm "playing" with Unity 5 and in my game, when I move -5 X units my player sprite disappears. I will let my movement script below and if you need more information to help me please ask.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public float forcaPulo; //means jump
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Movimentacao(); // means movement
    }
    void Movimentacao() {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0) {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0) {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 180);
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * forcaPulo);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly flipping the sprite around `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0, 180);`

There shouldn't be a need to rotate the sprite on the `y` axis. You've either meant to rotate on the `z` axis or its not needed.

Comment: My game is a 2d game so how can I change the sprite and/or the orientation of my player without changing it?

Comment: I think you meant to rotate it on another axis? `y` axis rotation does not conform with the rendered view.

Comment: @Andrew Maybe António doesn't understand how to rotate around other axes. Including an example using a `Vector3` to rotate around Z would be helpful.